# How to test flutter app after production?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, production-environment

so i am newbie in software development.I am using flutter to develop app and Firebase as back End .Now I have launched my app in production and the app fetch/write data from Firebase.
how do i test read/write for new release. Do i create duplicate database or perform read/write in the same database.

Comment: no, i mean for the new release. i have to check if the query are working properly or not before releasing the new version.

Answer (score 0):

I think safer and clear is to create a new Firebase project for testing and build the app for Test flavor then mix test data with production and control somehow that is a test record in DB and this is a test action.

Answer (score 0):

Create a another firebase project with same collections and use that db for testing and use flavor in flutter to work with two dbs with a single command .